# starting apache ignite from spring, hibernate l2 cache

Tags: spring, hibernate, ignite

I have tried both instantiating the IgniteSpringBean and manually calling Ignition.start() from java, but no matter what, I get this. This example is where I call Ignition.start() from java, log message is "DONE WITH IGNITION !" (logged after Ignition.start() is complete). Does the empty "name=" mean something? Maybe hibernate doesn't know what the instance name is?

```
Jan 11, 2018 3:09:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/api.war
Jan 11, 2018 3:10:12 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger warning
WARNING: Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
Jan 11, 2018 3:10:12 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger warning
WARNING: Checkpoints are disabled (to enable configure any GridCheckpointSpi implementation)
Jan 11, 2018 3:10:12 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger warning
WARNING: Collision resolution is disabled (all jobs will be activated upon arrival).
Jan 11, 2018 3:10:13 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger warning
WARNING: Nodes started on local machine require more than 80% of physical RAM what can lead to significant slowdown due to swapping (please decrease JVM heap size, data region size or checkpoint buffer size) [required=13549MB, available=16049MB]
01-11-2018 15:10:14.954 [localhost-startStop-1] {env=''} WARN  c.s.s.d.i.MyLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! DONE WITH IGNITION !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
01-11-2018 15:10:14.968 [localhost-startStop-1] {env=''} WARN  c.s.s.d.i.MyLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! DONE WITH ENTITY MANAGER FACTORY CONSTRUCTOR !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
01-11-2018 15:10:15.625 [localhost-startStop-1] {env=''} INFO  c.s.s.d.i.MyLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'cloudorch-jpa'
01-11-2018 15:10:21.389 [localhost-startStop-1] {env=''} WARN  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryJpa' defined in URL [file:/opt/cloud-orchestrator/etc/config/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) ~[spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_121]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_121]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteIllegalStateException: Ignite instance with provided name doesn't exist. Did you call Ignition.start(..) to start an Ignite instance? [name=]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.grid(IgnitionEx.java:1312) ~[ignite-core-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.ignite(Ignition.java:530) ~[ignite-core-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.cache.hibernate.HibernateRegionFactory.start(HibernateRegionFactory.java:107) ~[ignite-hibernate-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.<init>(CacheImpl.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:251) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
        ... 38 common frames omitted
01-11-2018 15:10:21.411 [localhost-startStop-1] {env=''} ERROR o.s.w.c.ContextLoader: Context initialization failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using a very old version of `ignite-hibernate` module:

```
~[ignite-hibernate-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
```

Make sure that version for all Ignite artifact you use is the same (e.g. 2.3.0).

Comment: Of course, thanks. I was misled, because when I went to this page, 1.0.0 is the latest (which I thought was weird): https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ignite/ignite-hibernate

Comment: You should use either `ignite-hibernate_5.1` or `ignite-hibernate_4.2` depending on Hibernate version you're using. You don't need to explicitly import `hibernate-core`, this is just a common module that other two depend on. Note that you won't find these modules in Maven central or any other Apache repos due to licensing. You can build from source or use 3rd party repos: https://ignite.apache.org/download.cgi#3rdparty

Comment: I see now. I have to build one of those and install to my maven repo. Finally, after reading various pieces of the ignite documentation, I kind of figured that out. The docs for the hibernate piece and the main maven build instructions are slightly contradictory, so that misled me. At various places, the hibernate module is referred to as ignite-hibernate, ignite-hibernate-core, ignite-hibernate_4.2, ignite-hibernate_5.1. Also, the lack of modules on maven central led me down the wrong track in the beginning.